# How to selecting multiple google sheets in pandas an apply code to all of them

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-colaboratory

I have some data from a google sheet and I was wondering if there was a way to apply code to all of the sheets at once. I also wish to know if it is possible to set the Date(which is in the format year-month-day hour:minute: second) based off the google sheet name and file name. What I mean by this is if the title of the google sheet is 2019.01, the month would be January and if the sheet name (the one at the bottom) is 24, the day would be 24. This would result in the date being 2019-01-24. Here is a picture of my current DateTime column (the leftmost one):
[image: A portion of my data in google colaboratory]

While the picture above shows that the DateTime is correct, I want to automate this with the spreadsheet and sheet name. Below is code that I have tried to apply to multiple google sheets at once, but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried to use 
    Janone = Jan.worksheet('01', '02', etc)
but this doesn't seem to work. Additionally, the second to the last line of code is the only format that seems to work or else I get the error: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:30:00. I haven't even been able to figure out the basics of the code for the DateTime that I want.

```
Jan = gc.open_by_url(disclosed for privacy)
Jan = Jan.worksheets()
january = get_as_dataframe(Jan)
january = pd.DataFrame(january)
new_header = january.iloc[0]
january = january[1:]
january.columns = new_header
january['DateTime'] = january['DateTime'].str.slice(6)
january['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 ' + january['DateTime'])
january
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'spreadsheet' is an error that I get from the code above. I wish to use the google sheet name as the dates and how to apply the code to multiple pandas at once.

Comment: Where does the ‘spreadsheet’ of your attributeError come from? I don’t see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: the error comes from the fact that my data is on a google spreadsheet

Comment: So the error comes from a part of your code that you haven’t posted. That makes it a bit hard to help. Also post an example of your current ‘DateTime’ column, as it is stored in the Google sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your DateTime problem. Try replacing your third and second to last lines with

```
january['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(january['DateTime'])
```

But that still doesn't explain your `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'spreadsheet'`, since there is no `spreadsheet` attribute used in your posted code.

Comment: that didn't work. I got an Unknown string format error. Also, this code would allow me to automate the process as much as I would like

Comment: The spreadsheet error is from the imported google spreadsheet